# video.js player not working on google chrome web browser but works on IE and Safari

Tags: video.js

I am having problem with video.js video player in google chrome web browser. The player was playing videos without any problem in all browsers until 2 days ago and then I observed that some videos won't play or won't load on chrome but all the videos play fine in internet explorer and safari browsers. Sometimes when I refresh page on chrome, some videos start to work but not others on the page.

my website url to check the problem is : 
http://titanimplants.com/education/

Video player I am using : http://videojs.com/
Player Version: 5.0.2
Video format: mp4
Chrome browser Version 46.0.2490.80 m

Any help is appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

First remark, why you use (and deactivate) 5.0.0/video.js?

```
<!-- Video.js -->
<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0.2/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">
<!--<script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0.0/video.js"></script> --> 
<!--<link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/4.12/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet">-->
```